# Installing Moonlight? Extracting .crx files?

Tags: 13.04, firefox, 64-bit, chromium, moonlight

I am trying to install moonlight on my 13.04 64-bit ubuntu system. I am using chromium as my main browser and firefox as backup.

I read that to install the moonlight downloaded .crx file in chromium, first I have to extract the .crx contents.

Can someone help me with the how-to to extract .crx file?

Also, is there an easier way of installing moonlight? And would my install cater to both of my browsers?

Comment: you can also try the latest, [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you point Firefox to http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight/, get to the download page and click on download after selecting the 64bit architecture, it will automatically install the extension.

Chrome/Chromium/Iron, on the other hand, [will prevent the `.crx` extension to be installed automatically](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?p=crx_warning&rd=1).

In this case, after you have downloaded the `.crx` file from the Moonlight download page (using Chrome), go to the **Tools** | **Extensions** configuration page, and then drag the `.crx` file onto the Chrome extensions page. It will ask for your permission to install the extension.

---

The `.xpi` extension package "[is simply a ZIP file containing the extension files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Extension_Packaging)", so you can open it just like any other `.zip` file. Note that you might need to change the extension of the file to `.zip`, depending on the method you use to extract the files.

One simple way to extract the contents of a downloaded `.xpi`, is with the use [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/), which can be easily installed:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mc
```

Navigate to the folder where the file has been downloaded and it can be opened like a folder and its contents copied out with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Once done installing, one can check if the silverlight functionality is working on the browser by using the tests on the page http://www.bubblemark.com/. Particularly the "Silverlight 3.0 (CLR, CacheMode="BitmapCache") new" test to check the SIlverlight 3.0

Comment: As of July 7, 2013, the link you give for Firefox is broken (403: Forbidden).

Comment: As of 2013-07-17, there seems to be no possibility to download. Please check the following addresses: http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight/ and http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight/Preview. Also, this link should be helpful: http://www.mono-project.com/MoonlightRoadmap

Comment: Why the use of Midnight Commander when xpi files are just zipped directiries?

Comment: @Braiam: Thank you for your comment. I put `mc` for no reason other than simplicity. I have updated my answer to reflect the fact that any method to open a `.zip` file is valid.

Answer (score -1):

Type

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

then install the crx extension in the extensions page of chrome