# How can I fix silverLight problem?

Tags: moonlight

*I want to explain my problem with `Images and Links`,but I don't have reputations so I posted same question in the following link.*

[How To install Moonlight on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694706/how-to-install-moonlight-on-ubuntu-machine)

*can check it and suggest me.
Thanks*

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`.I tried to open this [link](https://coxy7ezff6.database.windows.net/).I got the page in the following way.[image]
I searched some forums, one guy suggested `Ubuntu` not supported to `silverlight` so you need to install `moonlight`.

so I downloaded `moonlight` from this [site](http://www.4shared.com/file/D2uVB5uQ/novell-moonlight-39903-x86_64.htm).I installed in the following way

1. Open Firefox and drag and drop the file into `Firefox`.it shows successfully installed.

I reopen `Firefox` and reopen these same [Microsoft site](https://coxy7ezff6.database.windows.net/).It showing blank page(white page).like this
[image]

How can I fix this, can anyone suggest me

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As well as I understood, you are trying to open a database section on win..net. 
Moonlight instead of silverlight can be good but it may not support those databases.

You can read this [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298809/installing-moonlight-extracting-crx-files) for installing moonlight extension to firefox/chrome.

Chrome installation:
http://chrome.google.com

Comment: How can I install In `Google Chrome`.

Comment: Just open the `Ubuntu Software Center` and type in the search field (upper right corner) `chromium`. chrome is called chromium in Ubuntu.

Comment: @MrSeed already I installed `Chromium`.I asking initialization of `SliverLight` in `Google Chromo(Chromium)`

Comment: Moonlight 3.0 doesn't seem to be available as of 2013-07-17. Check http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight/Preview and http://www.mono-project.com/MoonlightRoadmap. On the other hand, with moonlight extension installed previously on Iron (Chromium clone), I wasn't able to see anything in the address @urtrulyfriend refers to.

Comment: You can find .crx file at this [link](http://mokeke.sytes.net/downloads/linux/Novell_Moonlight/) 
You can read the installation from this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235532/how-can-i-install-moonlight-for-chrome-in-12-04/235588#235588)

Comment: @ikorucu77 I follow same Initialization steps,what they mention in link. again I faced some problem here.It's showing blank(white) page. I tried to open this following link.
`https://coxy7ezff6.database.windows.net/`