# Microsoft silverlight not in Ubuntu 13.04 Netflix desktop app

Tags: 13.04, 32-bit, netflix

I thought it would be fun to put Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on my PC, I have been told Netflix would work on 64-bit, bit it didn't. I checked terminal, long story short with 64-bit was I don't know what foreign architecture support and I don't know how to use it. I dual operated it with Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit and got the Netflix desktop app and now I need Microsoft silverlight. Please help me I am at my witts end. I need to know how to use netflix on Ubuntu 13.04 32 or 64 bit (terminal says i386 in foreign architecture support in 64-bit). thanks

Comment: you might want to consider, [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Moonlight? Extracting .crx files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298809/installing-moonlight-extracting-crx-files) describes how to install Moonlight, the open source equivalent to Silverlight, into Ubuntu.

Comment: Netflix uses DRM technology, which open-source programs, such as Moonlight, never support. Therefore, Moonlight will not work at all in this case.

Comment: the site says it's forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You could try manually downloading/installing Silverlight. If you try to do so from Microsoft's website, you'll only be directed to Moonlight, which is ill-suited for Netflix. However, you can download the Windows version from [HERE](http://www.filehippo.com/download_silverlight/).

Or, you could also see what happens when you install Pipelight. Pipelight is a browser plugin, which allows you to use Netflix from within you native browser. For installation Instructions, see [HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html).

Comment: I have a hard time installing it, do I need to use Wine?